# Make paid Android app free for a week?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid Android app that costs some $. I would like to make it free for a certain period of time. I.e. a promotional price of $0. In Google Play, there is an option to make an app free but when I check it, it says:

*"Setting the price to Free is permanent; you cannot change to a price later."*

That's certainly not what I want! After a week I want to set my original price back! So...

**Q:** How can I have a promotional price of $0 during, lets say, a week?

Comment: Would be good to know but it seems more like a business question to Google than programming.

Comment: Certainly. Still, I would argue that this question is highly relevant for app developers. Google Play Developer Console is a developer's tool :)

Comment: How about selling it dirt cheap for that period of time?

Comment: It's a semi-ok workaround, yes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not possible due to potential ways to exploit the workings of the Google Play store (potentially skewing download counts, and such; a free app is more likely to get downloads, and those will boost its rankings before you make it cost money).

This has been [asked before](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/-vYcbqzSPsI), and the consensus is that it's not possible by design. There are a few solutions in that thread, such as:

- Make your app free, last one week, then have the user use in-app purchasing to continue using it. (Not sure if this is exactly what you hoped, but it's a potential way of monetizing regardless.)
- Put up a free version, and take it down in a week. Users will have to reinstall the app to get the paid version but this would still have the same desired effect.
- Do an update (or have a setting in your app that expires at a certain time) to remove the paid features after a week (this might tick off a lot of users, though).

Sadly, as I said, this is not possible, so you'll just have to work around it best you can.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! It's a shame this cannot be done in a better way.

Comment: Then what will be the concept 'watsapp' is using??

Comment: @Tony When did WhatsApp go from free to paid?

Comment: Can an in-app purchase be a one time purchase? and is their an api to check? would google shut down my app if i used another processor to collect payment?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but for those still looking for an answer, you could do something in the app that forces the user to buy the paid version after a week. Ex. Cerberus. You get a free trial for 6 days. After the time is up, each time you open the app, it takes you to the paid store listing. Just a tip.

Comment: great idea. Does the trial cut off have to be coded into the trial version?  Are you required to say it's a free trail? This will require you to pay to deployment and maintain two versions. Also, how do you handle de-installing free version?  It is a shame this is not a feature.  BTW, will google remove my app if I try to bill through another processor like paypal?