# make android app free for one year then make option to subscribe the app

Tags: android, google-play

[Followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618015/make-paid-android-app-free-for-a-week) but didn't get it. Followed developers page found in app billing option so gone through [Google console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504) and [android in app billing version 3.0](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttypes) but there specifying subscription for products, I want to make whole app to subscribe for one year only after one year trial period, and these settings are make only in google console? Or if I need to programmatically implement this?, give me brief idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You Should have Tie up with any one of payment services such as PayPal, Epay, Pay world. Then, only you will make the **Subscribe** option. Programmatically will give the solution like one scheduler will run for 365 days. After that will go to **Subscribe** option.

For more please [read here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx).

Comment: I also had same problem,gone through u r link,nothing related to question.

Comment: Please [Click Here] (http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx)..It will useful for Your Problem..